# Swift: how to finish a UIView draw animation before changing a label

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewanimation

I have a little problem regarding the timing of an animation.

The sequence should be:

1. Button is pressed
2. Animation is displayed
3. Label is changed

In reality the sequence is:

1. Button is pressed
2. Label is changed
3. Animation is displayed

Here is the code of the main VC:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MainVC: UIViewController {

  var counter: Int = 0

  @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!
  
  @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!

  @IBOutlet weak var animationView: AnimationView!

  @IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
     counter += 1
     animationView.progress = 1
     //this view draws a progress bar and animates it from 0 to 100% via CABasicAnimation. 
     counterLabel.text = "\(counter)"
     animationView.progress = 0 
     //the progress bar is reset
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     nextButton.setTitle("Next")
     counterLabel.text = "\(counter)"
  }

}
```

I've experimented with the dispatch queue, but I just can't get it to work right. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show enough of your code for us to be able to help you specifically.

In general, you would set some object to be the delegate of your CAAnimation, and implement the method `func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool)`.

In that method you'd then change the label text (assuming `finished == true`.)

I don't really like the delegate pattern for animations. If you have multiple animations it can be painful to handle custom completion code for each one. What I've done is use the fact that you can attach objects to CAAnimation objects, and attach a closure to the animation. I then set the view controller to be the delegate, and in the view controller's `animationDidStop()`, I look for a closure attached to the animation, and execute it if there is one.

### Edit:

See this article for a discussion on using key-value coding to attach objects to `CAAnimation` and `CALayer` objects:

[**Core Animation Key-value coding extensions**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html)

It's old, and written using Objective-C, but the concepts are the same in Swift, and very useful. For a more general discussion on key-value coding, which **is** updated for Swift, see this article: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/nskeyvaluecoding

(The two functions you need to know in Swift are `setValue(_:forKeyPath:)` and `value(forKey:)`.)

Comment: This is actually very helpful, I will try using the delegate pattern. I only have this one animation, so it should not be too complicated.

Comment: If I've answered your question you should accept my answer.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for your help! I'm a newbie to Swift and did not know about the delegate func animationDidStop.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Well done figuring it out if you're a newbie! Do you have experience in other languages?

Comment: When you look at classes like `CABasicAnimation`, remember to check methods in their ancestor classes. `CABasicAnimation` is a subclass of `CAAnimation`, and the delegate property is defined in the parent class. The `animationDidStop()` method is documented in the section on `CAAnimationDelegate`. It's a pretty common design pattern in iOS/MacOS for an object to have a delegate property that defines methods that get called to notify you about changes in status, or give you a chance to customize the behavior of the "delegated" object.

Comment: Note that `UIView` animation methods like `animate(withDuration:animations:completion:)` are better documented and much easier to use than CAAnimation and CALayer. There are some things you can't do with `UIView` animation, but where possible, I would suggest using them instead of `CAAnimation`.

Comment: Back in the 90s I was doing some stuff in Basic and Pascal, but that's about it with programming knowledge. I started with Swift about 8 months ago just to see if I could get something working. I'm mostly doing it for fun and don't know if I will ever get something in the App Store... Thanks for your recommendations, I will keep them in mind!